# Microsoft OData client property notification on commit

Tags: c#, uwp, odata

I have an application that has been in production for a while. I recently upgraded all the NuGet packages and moved to Microsoft OData v7.4.1 Well, now my data services that had been working are excepting with the "Wrong thread..." message on the commit. The property that is being changed is a foreign key property but I can't seem to find any reason this event is being raised. Any help tracking this down would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the exact error:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x8001010E
  Message=The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Comment: Did this issue only occur in UWP project?

Comment: I have not tried it on a WPF project. But think I understand what is happening. I had directly bound some properties in a data object to a textbox, etc. and that was causing a property notification to be added to the object. When my data service layer wrote this to the DB, it triggered that notification which was then running on the OData client thread, hence the exception. I've worked around that by using a intermediate property in the view model.